# Button behavior in django template (href + function)

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a next problem:

```
<div class="col-4">
    
    <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{% url 'home' %}" role="button">Save and Back</a>
    {{ request | mail}}
    
</div>
```

The logic is next: I want to click on button and send an email with redirecting to home page. My `mail` is a filter tag. Unfortunately I can't add my filter to the view, because I am using this view in another place, where I don't want to send an email.  My current solution send an email before click on button. Do you have any idea? 
my **view.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
    
    # logined user block
    user = get_user(request)
    user_gpds = get_user_gpd(user)

    context ={'user':user, 'user_gpds':user_gpds, 'is_manager':log_user_is_manager(request)}
    return render(request, 'app/home_page/home_page.html', context)
```

my **filter tag**

```
import re
from django import template
from django.core.mail import send_mail
register = template.Library()
from django.template.loader import render_to_string


@register.filter
def mail(request):
    msg_plain = render_to_string('app/team_gpds/email.txt', {'request': request})
    return send_mail(
    'System Notification: Please accept GPD',
    msg_plain,
    '.......',
    ['....@....',],
    fail_silently=False,
    )
```

my **email.txt**

```
Follow the White Rabbit:

{{ request.scheme }}://{{ request.get_host }}{% url 'home' %}
```

my **url.py**

```
path('home/', views.home, name="home"),
```

Comment: could you please share your view ?

Comment: I've added info to my question